# Ansible - How to combine list attributes?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jq, ansible-inventory

I have two separate lists. The first is a list (base_list) with basic parameters, and the second is a list (dev_list) with parameters for a specific stand.

```
"base_list": [
    {
        "name": "kibana",
        "path": "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
    },
    {
        "name": "logstash",
        "path": "logstash/conf/logstash.yml",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/logstash/conf/logstash.yml"
    },
    {
        "name": "grafana",
        "path": "grafana/conf/grafana.json",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/grafana.json"
    },
    {
        "name": "grafana",
        "path": "grafana/conf/nginx.json",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/nginx.json"
    },
    {
        "name": "grafana",
        "path": "grafana/conf/config.json",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/config.json"
    },
]

"dev_list": [
    {
        "name": "kibana",
        "path": "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
    },
    {
        "name": "logstash",
        "path": "logstash/conf/jvm.options",
        "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/logstash/conf/jvm.options"
    }
]
```

My goal is to combine these two lists to get one item.name with several item.path and item.src. Paths that look like this:

```
"end_list": [
        {
            "name": "kibana", 
            "path": "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "logstash", 
            "path": [
                "logstash/conf/logstash.yml", 
                "logstash/conf/jvm.options"
            ], 
            "src": [
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/logstash/conf/logstash.yml", 
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/logstash/conf/jvm.options"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "grafana",
            "path": [
                "grafana/conf/grafana.json",
                "grafana/conf/nginx.json",
                "grafana/conf/config.json"
            ]
            "src": [
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/grafana.json",
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/nginx.json",
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/config.json"
            ]
        },
    ]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: This Q has the [jq] tag but the "expected output" is not valid JSON, so I'm wondering whether JSON output would be acceptable.

Comment: You are right, my "expected output" is not correct. @larsks made the right JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be easier with a custom Python filter, but here's a solution using Ansible's built-in filters:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    "base_list": [
        {
            "name": "kibana",
            "path": "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "logstash",
            "path": "logstash/conf/logstash.yml",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/logstash/conf/logstash.yml"
        },
        {
            "name": "grafana",
            "path": "grafana/conf/grafana.json",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/grafana.json"
        },
    ]

    "dev_list": [
        {
            "name": "kibana",
            "path": "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "logstash",
            "path": "logstash/conf/jvm.options",
            "src": "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/logstash/conf/jvm.options"
        }
    ]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        end_list: >-
          {{ end_list|default([]) + [
          {
          'name': item.0.name,
          'path': item.1.path|ternary([item.0.path, item.1.path], item.0.path),
          'src': item.1.src|ternary([item.0.src, item.1.src], item.1.src)
          }
          ]}}
      loop: >-
        {{ base_list|zip_longest(dev_list,
        fillvalue={'path': false, 'src': false})|list }}

    - debug:
        var: end_list
```

This was a little tricky to put together, so I'll try to describe the various parts:

The loop uses the [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) filter.  Given the lists `list1=[1, 2, 3]` and `list2=[11, 12]`, `list1|zip_longest(list2)` would produce `[[1,11], [2,12], [3,None]]` (that is, by default, `zip_longest` will use `None` as a fill value if one list is shorter than the other).  By setting the `fillvalue` parameter, we can use a value other than `None`.  In this case...

```
loop: >-
  {{ base_list|zip_longest(dev_list,
  fillvalue={'path': false, 'src': false})|list }}
```

...We're setting the fill value to a dictionary with stub values for `path` and `src`, since this makes the rest of the expression easier.

The meat of the solution is of course the `set_fact` action, which in simplified form looks like:

```
end_list: "{{ end_list|default([]) + [{...a dictionary...}] }}"
```

In other words, for each iteration of the `loop`, this will append a new dictionary to `end_list`.

We create the dictionary like this:

```
{
'name': item.0.name,
'path': item.1.path|ternary([item.0.path, item.1.path], item.0.path),
'src': item.1.src|ternary([item.0.src, item.1.src], item.1.src)
}
```

We're using the `ternary` filter here, which evaluates it's input as a boolean; if it's `true`, it selects the first argument, otherwise the second. Here we're taking advantage of the `fillvalue` we passed to the `zip_longest` filter: if `dev_list` is shorter than `base_list`, we'll have some items for which `item.1.path` and `item.1.src` are `false`, causing the ternary filter to select the second value (either `item.0.path` or `item.1.src`).  In other cases, we build a list by combining the values from each of `base_list` and `dev_list`.

The result of running this playbook looks like:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "end_list": [
        {
            "name": "kibana", 
            "path": [
                "kibana/conf/kibana.xml", 
                "kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
            ], 
            "src": [
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml", 
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "logstash", 
            "path": [
                "logstash/conf/logstash.yml", 
                "logstash/conf/jvm.options"
            ], 
            "src": [
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/logstash/conf/logstash.yml", 
                "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/logstash/conf/jvm.options"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "grafana", 
            "path": "grafana/conf/grafana.json", 
            "src": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if that helps, and whether or not the resulting data structure is what you were looking for. I had to make a few assumptions since your example `end_list` contained invalid syntax, so I took a guess at what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and comment. But this is not exactly what I would like to receive. It turns out you need to compare only the elements of the first list with the second and group them. And if the elements in the first list are combined with the second, then take the element only from the second list (dev_list).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had well-formed json and those are properties on the root object, jq is perfectly suited for this.  Group the contents of the arrays by name then generate the appropriate result objects.

```
$ jq '{
    end_combine: (
        .base_list + .dev_list
          | group_by(.name)
          | map({ name: .[0].name, path: map(.path), src: map(.src) })
    )
}' input.json
```

```
{
  "end_combine": [
    {
      "name": "grafana",
      "path": [
        "grafana/conf/grafana.json",
        "grafana/conf/nginx.json",
        "grafana/conf/config.json"
      ],
      "src": [
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/grafana.json",
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/nginx.json",
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/grafana/conf/config.json"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "kibana",
      "path": [
        "kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
        "kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
      ],
      "src": [
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml",
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/kibana/conf/kibana.xml"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "logstash",
      "path": [
        "logstash/conf/logstash.yml",
        "logstash/conf/jvm.options"
      ],
      "src": [
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/_base/group_vars/logstash/conf/logstash.yml",
        "/Users/ansible/inventories/dev-st/group_vars/logstash/conf/jvm.options"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```